# How can I test an input with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I've been trying to figure out how to test different input methods but since I am new to this test methodology, I cannot get even close to the answer. Here is what I have:

```
const App = (props) => {
    const newGame = props.newGame;
    const [typeracertext, setTyperacertext] = useState(props.typeracertext);
    const [wholeText, setWholeText] = useState("");

    const onChange = (e) => {

       //here I have code that read the input and is comparing it with variable - typeracertext and if so, it sets the property wholeText to that value
};
    return (
        <input ref={(node) => this.textInput = node}  placeholder="Message..." onChange={onChange}></input> 
    );
}
```

so what I am trying to figure out is a test that should set the typeracertext to a certain value (for example "This is a test), and set the input value to "This" so if it passes the onChange() check it should set wholeText to "This". I hope that makes sense.

This is the best I could get and I don't have an idea what should I write on "expect".

```
test('Test the input value', () => {
const node = this.textInput;
node.value = 'This';
ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(node);
expect()
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Since this is a react app, I'll advice you take advantage of react testing library to make this easy

```js
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

// In describe block
test('Test input component', () => {
  const onChange = jest.fn();
  render(<InputComponent onChange={onChange} data-test-id="input" />);
  const input = screen.getByTestId('input');
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'a value' } });
  // You can also do this with userEvent
  userEvent.type(input, 'test')
  // Check if change event was fired
  expect((input as HTMLInputElement).onchange).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

See documentation [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/)

Comment: This isn't testing around the application and you didn't incorporate anything the question posited around the behavior.  All this does is test if an unspecified component `InputComponent` which you invented acts like an input.